# Intune azure graph api to Create deviceCompliancePolicyState Returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: api, azure, microsoft-graph-api, intune

Call

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/managedDevices/dd9615c4-9d3b-4ece-9272-34a10e8fe908/
```

RESPONSE

```
 {
      "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#managedDevices/$entity",
      "id": "dd9615c4-9d3b-4ece-9272-34a10e8fe908",
      "userId": null,
      "deviceName": "iPad Feb23",
      "hardwareInformation": {
        "serialNumber": null,
        "totalStorageSpace": 0,
        "freeStorageSpace": 0,
        "imei": "",
        "meid": null,
        "manufacturer": null,
        "model": null,
        "phoneNumber": null,
        "subscriberCarrier": null,
        "cellularTechnology": null,
        "wifiMac": null,
        "operatingSystemLanguage": null,
        "isSupervised": false,
        "isEncrypted": false,
        "isSharedDevice": false,
        "sharedDeviceCachedUsers": []
      },
      "ownerType": "personal",
      "deviceActionResults": [],
      "managementState": "managed",
      "enrolledDateTime": "2017-05-24T13:10:20.8964572Z",
      "lastSyncDateTime": "2017-05-24T15:16:02.6465376Z",
      "chassisType": "tablet",
      "operatingSystem": "iOS",
      "deviceType": "iPad",

  "complianceState": "compliant",
  "jailBroken": "False",
  "managementAgents": 2,
  "managementAgent": "mdm",
  "osVersion": "9.3.5",
  "easActivated": false,
  "easDeviceId": null,
  "easActivationDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "aadRegistered": null,
  "enrollmentType": "userEnrollmentWithServiceAccount",
  "lostModeState": "disabled",
  "activationLockBypassCode": null,
  "emailAddress": null,
  "azureActiveDirectoryDeviceId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "deviceRegistrationState": "registered",
  "deviceCategoryDisplayName": null,
  "isSupervised": false,
  "exchangeLastSuccessfulSyncDateTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "exchangeAccessState": "none",
  "exchangeAccessStateReason": "none",
  "remoteAssistanceSessionUrl": "",
  "isEncrypted": false,
  "model": null,
  "manufacturer": null
}
```

But when i try to do post nothing seems to work ... according to the doc here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/intune_mam_mobileappidentifierdeployment_create

it should work just fine what is the problem with this call ...?

Call

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/managedDevices/dd9615c4-9d3b-4ece-9272-34a10e8fe908/deviceCompliancePolicyStates/

{
  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.deviceCompliancePolicyState",
  "settingStates": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.deviceCompliancePolicySettingState",
      "setting": "Setting value",
      "instanceDisplayName": "Instance Display Name value",
      "state": "notApplicable",
      "errorCode": 9,
      "errorDescription": "Error Description value",
      "userPrincipalName": "User Principal Name value",
      "sources": [
        {
          "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.settingSource",
          "id": "Id value",
          "displayName": "Display Name value"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "displayName": "Display Name value",
  "version": 7,
  "platformType": "androidForWork",
  "state": "notApplicable",
  "settingCount": 12
}
```

RESPONSE

```
    {
  "error": {
    "code": "No method match route template",
    "message": "No OData route exists that match template ~/entityset/key/navigation with http verb POST for request /StatelessDeviceConfigurationFEService/managedDevices('dd9615c4-9d3b-4ece-9272-34a10e8fe908')/deviceCompliancePolicyStates.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "544c4ee2-a6de-4203-9c30-c3e589b77713",
      "date": "2017-05-24T15:48:30"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an engineer on the Microsoft Intune team specifically working on the integration between Microsoft Graph and Microsoft Intune.

In this case it looks like there is an issue with the documentation as deviceCompliancePolicyState entity can not be created, it is read-only entity that shows the state of a device compliance policy. I will work to get the documentation corrected. If you can let me know what scenario you were trying to accomplish by creating a deviceCompliancePolicyState entity I may be able to point you in the right direction.

Hope that helps

Peter

Comment: I'm working on custom threat defnece connector kinda thing (  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/intune-classic/deploy-use/mobile-threat-defense) where I have a custom app on a device that checks for malware,...MITM .... and when it detects some malicious activity, i will set the deviceCompliancePolicy to "nonComliant" so that the conditional access kicks in and handles the rest i.e. block the device from accessing services. i tried to contact the support a number of times on how we can go about this but to no avail ...

Comment: can you point me to the right direction now? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176353/an-azure-app-how-to-send-device-threat-info-to-microsoft-intune